# UserControl Not Displaying in Word Add In

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to open a user control when an add in loads up. Here is the code in the Add-in Startup event handler:

```
    private SidePane sidePane;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane cTP;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        sidePane = new SidePane();
        cTP = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(sidePane, "MyTaskPane");
        cTP.Visible = true;
    }
```

When opens up nothing shows in the side pane, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you set ctp. width =int value ?

Comment: just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Can you check Addin is enable ?

Comment: Try my update code

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: yeah I tried that, maybe it's because my add in isn't enabled. How do I enable it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153054/discussion-between-shyam-sundar-shah-and-umdi-barram).

Comment: Alright I checked my add in and it is enabled

Comment: Let me know if you need further more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need set to width property

```
    public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane { get; set; }
    public CustomPaneUserControl cPaneUserControl = new CustomPaneUserControl();


    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        myCustomTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(cPaneUserControl, "Verime");
        myCustomTaskPane.Width = 300;
        myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
        myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
    }
```